# IPv4 Address BigEndian ByteOrder

Tags: go

I'm a bit confused about how Go binary package within the standard library represents integer into `[]byte` with BigEndian ordering.

For reference, below is the method in the standard library I'm confused with:

```
    func (bigEndian) PutUint32(b []byte, v uint32) {
    _ = b[3] // early bounds check to guarantee safety of writes below
    b[0] = byte(v >> 24)
    b[1] = byte(v >> 16)
    b[2] = byte(v >> 8)
    b[3] = byte(v)
}
```

Suppose I have an IPv4 addressed represented as an unsigned 32-bits integer such as 236194314

With a BigEndian ordering, this should be represented as 4-bytes slice: `[10 10 20 14]`

However, the PutUint32 stores the most significant byte in the array in the last index `b[3] = byte(v)` resulting in  `[14 20 10 10]`.

Is there any specific explanation for this?

Comment: `b[3]=byte(v)` (10) is the least significant byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 236194314 is 0E 14 0A 0A in hex. So the most significant byte is indeed 14d. Your IPv4 addressed represented as an unsigned 32-bits integer comes in already byte reversed.

The problem happened before you convert to a byte slice.